# Does casting `std::floor()` and `std::ceil()` to integer type always give the correct result?

Tags: c++, math, floating-accuracy, arithmetic-expressions

I am being paranoid that one of these functions may give an incorrect result like this:

```
std::floor(2000.0 / 1000.0) --> std::floor(1.999999999999) --> 1
or
std::ceil(18 / 3) --> std::ceil(6.000000000001) --> 7
```

Can something like this happen? If there is indeed a risk like this, I'm planning to use the functions below in order to work safely. But, is this really necessary?

```
constexpr long double EPSILON = 1e-10;

intmax_t GuaranteedFloor(const long double & Number)
{
    if (Number > 0)
    {
        return static_cast<intmax_t>(std::floor(Number) + EPSILON);
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<intmax_t>(std::floor(Number) - EPSILON);
    }
}

intmax_t GuaranteedCeil(const long double & Number)
{
    if (Number > 0)
    {
        return static_cast<intmax_t>(std::ceil(Number) + EPSILON);
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<intmax_t>(std::ceil(Number) - EPSILON);
    }
}
```

(Note: I'm assuming that the the given 'long double' argument will fit in the 'intmax_t' return type.)

Comment: I would think those examples would be safe (whole numbers, within precision of floating-point) but, for instance, "3.3 / 1.1" could conceivably give "not precisely 3".

Comment: `EPSILON` won't save you. It is the smallest significant amount of difference **at 1.0**, i.e. the smallest value you can add to 1.0 to get a different value. If your result might be larger or smaller than 1.0, you would need a different `EPSILON`. If you think you need `EPSILON` for anything, chances are you're about to introduce a very subtle bug in your software.

Comment: Instead of a `static_cast`, you might consider `std::lround`, which returns the nearest int: `int i = std::lround(std::ceil(f))` . This would remove the need for an epsilon or conditionals.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

People often get the impression that floating point operations produce results with small, unpredictable, quasi-random errors. This impression is incorrect.

Floating point arithmetic computations are *as exact as possible*. `18/3` will always produce *exactly 6*. The result of `1/3` won't be exactly one third, but it will be *the closest number to one third that is representable as a floating point number*.

So the examples you showed are guaranteed to always work. As for your suggested "guaranteed floor/ceil", it's not a good idea. Certain sequences of operations can easily blow the error far above `1e-10`, and certain other use cases will require `1e-10` to be correctly recognized (and ceil'ed) as nonzero.

As a rule of thumb, hardcoded epsilon values are bugs in your code.

Answer (score 4):

In the specific examples you're listing, I don't think those errors would ever occur.

```
std::floor(2000.0 /*Exactly Representable in 32-bit or 64-bit Floating Point Numbers*/ / 1000.0 /*Also exactly representable*/) --> std::floor(2.0 /*Exactly Representable*/) --> 2
std::ceil(18 / 3 /*both treated as ints, might not even compile if ceil isn't properly overloaded....?*/) --> 6
std::ceil(18.0 /*Exactly Representable*/ / 3.0 /*Exactly Representable*/) --> 6
```

Having said that, if you have math that depends on these functions behaving exactly correctly for floating point numbers, that may illuminate a design flaw you need to reconsider/reexamine.

Answer (score 1):

**As long as the floating-point values x and y exactly represent integers within the limits of the type you're using, there's no problem--`x / y` will always yield a floating-point value that exactly represents the integer result.** Casting to int as you're doing will always work.

However, once the floating-point values go outside the integer-representable range for the type ([Representing integers in doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759201/representing-integers-in-doubles)), epsilons don't help.

Consider this example. 16777217 is the smallest integer not exactly representable as a 32-bit `float`:

```
int ix=16777217, iy=97;
printf("%d / %d = %d", ix, iy, ix/iy);
// yields "16777217 / 97 = 172961" which is accurate

float x=ix, y=iy;
printf("%f / %f = %f", x, y, x/y);
// yields "16777216.000000 / 97.000000 = 172960.989691"
```

In this case, the error is negative; in other cases (try 16777219 / 1549), the error is positive.

While it's tempting to add an epsilon to make `floor` work, it won't extend the accuracy much. **When the values differ by more orders of magnitude, the error becomes greater than 1 and integer-accuracy can't be guaranteed.** Specifically, when `x/y` exceeds the max. representable, the error can exceed 1.0, so the epsilon is no help.

If this is coming into play, you will have to consider changing your mathematical approach--order of operations, work with logarithms, etc.

Answer (score -6):

Such results are likely to appear when working with doubles. You can use round or you can subtract 0.5 then use std::ceil function.

Comment: The question is about calculations with operands *and results* that are representable as integer.