# Go: use slice of different numeric types as field of a struct

Tags: go, polymorphism, slice, go-interface

I am writing a collector that collects metrics and stores in structs that looks something like this:

```
type Metric struct {
  Name string
  Data []float64
}
```

However for some metrics, it does not make sense to use float64, since their values are unsigned integers. Any idea how I could use different numeric types for the `Data` field?

I could use `Data []interface{}`, but then I won't be able to use indexing on the array elements.

(For clarity: I don't need different types in one slice, like a list in Python: my slice has to be strongly typed, but I want to be able to change the type of the slice.)

Comment: What about defining another Metric struct, that stores data as type uint? Besides, why shouldn't you be able to use indexing on a slice of interfaces? [-> example](https://play.golang.org/p/oSiuSjCYNCx)

Comment: You cannot "change the type of the slice" just like you can't change the type of any other value. Use multiple fields or different struct types, as suggested above.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I am trying now to define an interface "vector" and work with that.

@MrFuppes, thanks, you're right, but doesn't this make the slice dynamically typed? performance is critical for my project, so I really want the same performance as with native slices.

Comment: For clarity, I wouldn't use a slice of interface if I had only two types (and I know which). Regarding the interface slice, the slice would be of interface type (so basically static); but each element could hold reference to a different type. Compared to a list in Python, a list is an object, it doesn't have a type in that sense.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I *don't* want - a python list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full solution to this, you'll have to wait until generics lands in Go (potentially in 1.18): https://blog.golang.org/generics-proposal

With generics, you'd be able to have a generic `Metric` type that can either hold `float64` or `unsigned`, and you could instantiate each of them separately.

E.g. ([generics-enabled playgorund](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/A3H1Dp1niHS)):

```
type Metric[T any] struct {
  Name string
  Data []T
}

func main() {
  mf := Metric[float64]{"foo", []float64{12.24, 1.1, 2.22}}
  mu := Metric[uint32]{"bar", []uint32{42, 2}}

  fmt.Println(mf)
  fmt.Println(mu)
}
```

Note that `[T any]` means that the type held in `Data` is unconstrained. You can constrain it to types with certain characteristics, or to a hardcoded list like `float64, uint32` if you prefer.

---

In the meanwhile, there are some options:

1. `float64` can represent a lot of integers; at least all 32-bit ones (see [Representing integers in doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759201/representing-integers-in-doubles))
2. You *can* use `Data []interface{}`, but it's rather wasteful. There should be no problem indexing into this slice, but you'll have to have type asserts whenever you work with it. It's costly both memory-wise and runtime performance-wise; something that can really matter for metrics.
3. You can have two versions of `Metric`, with code duplication (and use code generation to help, if needed).