# C++ Addition of very large unsigned long and double

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned long n = 10ul;
  unsigned long ul = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - n;
  double d = 1.;
  ul += d;
  std::cout << ul << std::endl;
}
```

One might expect that the output is `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - 9`. However, The output of this code is `0` for all values `n < 1024`. Why?

Some observations of what I'm thinking to understand so far:

1. We do not exceed `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` so no overflow of `ul` should happen (mathematically speaking).
2. Casting `d` while adding it results in the expected value for `ul` (change line 7 to `ul += static_cast<unsigned long>(d);`)
3. My guess at what happens:

   - `ul += d` is resolved to `ul = (double)ul + d`
   - This addition is executed as a 64-bit floating-point operation
   - The resulting value can not be represented precisely by `double` and turns out to be `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() + 1`.
   - This result is then cast back to `unsigned long`, which overflows/wraps around to 0.

**EDIT**

Some testing seems to support my guess above.

- `double x = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()` results in `x` holding the value `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() + 1`.
- Yes, my `unsigned long` is 64-bit.
- The question is not why `double` is not precise. I understand the concept of floating-point numbers. The question is what are the exact rules for `C++` for evaluating an expression in which data format that lead to this unfortunate result.

Comment: `double` can only approximate large 64bit integers so the result of your calculation is rounded before assigning back to `ul`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759201/representing-integers-in-doubles

Comment: @Seriously Did you check the size of your `unsigned long`? 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: @AlanBirtles is `ul = (double)ul + d;` what is going on? Not sure if the dupe alone is sufficient as answer.

Comment: Your guess looks correct, except that casting back to integer type is undefined behavior if it isn't in the integer type's range.

Comment: Side note: This question will work (as in give the mathematically correct result) on LLP64 systems (e.g. windows) as the maximum value of a unsigned long in that case is 2^32-1. And a double can perfectly represent integers in that range.

Comment: I think you can find the answer somewhere in here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion (that + the duplicate)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yep, its the cast to double and back that causes the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/GTvGqhT5q, note that enabling optimisations changes the result

Comment: Note that `std::cout << (unsigned long) (double) ul - ul << std::endl; ` gives 11. At least on my PC (UB !)

Comment: Easy way to test your theory, try `ul += (unsigned long)d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is what are the exact rules for C++ for evaluating an expression in which data format that lead to this unfortunate result.

Let's inspect the line:

```
ul += d;
```

Where `d` has type `double` and `ul` has type `unsigned long`.

From [7.6.19 Assignment and compound assignment operators](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#ass)  :

> The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once

So `ul += d` is equal to `ul = ul + d`.

From [7.6.6 Additive operators](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#add)  :

> The additive operators + and - group left-to-right.
> The *usual arithmetic conversions* are performed for operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

So both `ul` and `d` are promoted in `ul + d`.

From [7.4 Usual arithmetic conversions](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#arith.conv)  :

> [...] This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
> - [...]

So `ul` is converted to double in `ul + d`.

From [7.3.11 Floating-integral conversions](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#conv.fpint) emphasis mine:

> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating-point type.
> The result is exact if possible.
> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly, it is an **implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value**.
>
> If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

So it is implementation defined if the value of `ul` can't be represented exactly in double which value is used.

And then, after calculation, the `double` result is converted back to `unsigned long` in assignment to `ul`, so also from `Floating-integral conversions` emphasis mine:

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
> The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.
> **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type**.

---

> The output of this code is 0 for all values n < 1024. Why?

Gcc compiler documents that it follows C99 Annex F when converting floats to integers and back, see [gcc11.1.0 docs implementation defined beavior 4.6 Floating point](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Floating-point-implementation.html#Floating-point-implementation), but I see the result in [C99 Annex F](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#F.4) is unspecified, but a floating point exception is required to be raised. The following code with function copied from [cppreference feexceptflag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feexceptflag)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cfenv>

void show_fe_exceptions(void)
{
    printf("current exceptions raised: ");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))     printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))       printf(" FE_INEXACT");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))       printf(" FE_INVALID");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))      printf(" FE_OVERFLOW");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))     printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)==0) printf(" none");
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned long n = 10ul;
  unsigned long ul = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - n;
  double d = 1.;
  show_fe_exceptions();
  ul += d;
  show_fe_exceptions();
  std::cout << ul << std::endl;
}
```

[outputs on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hq5c8fG15) and confirms the exception is raised:

```
current exceptions raised:  none
current exceptions raised:  FE_INEXACT FE_INVALID
0
```

Comment: So a summary and answer to the question about the output being 0 would be "because it is unspecified behavior"?

Comment: Summa summarum yes.